# prove that for each $m \geq 2$, $|w_{m+1}-w_m| \leq (2/3)^{2(m-1)}|w_2 - w_1|$

Tags: real-analysis

If a sequence is given by $S_{n+1}=S_n + S_{n-1}$ where $S_1=1$ and $S_2=2$ and we let $w_n=S_n/S_{n-1}$ for all $n \geq 2$.

I trying to prove that for each $m \geq 2$, $|w_{m+1}-w_m| \leq  (2/3)^{2(m-1)}|w_2 - w_1|$, but I don't understand how. I think I need to start with $|w_{m+1}-w_m| =$ something that will eventually lead me to $(2/3)^{2(m-1)}|w_2 - w_1|$ , but I don't know what it would be, if I'm even thinking about this problem correctly. Could someone please explain/show how to prove this?

Comment: How about showing $\left | \frac{w_{m+1}-w_m}{w_2 - w_1} \right | \leq (2/3)^{2(m-1)}$ for $m\geq 2$ using induction?

Answer (score 0):

This is true for $m\ge3$ actually.

Once you see this for the base case, this is proven by induction if $|w_{m+1}-w_m|=(2/3)^2|w_m-w_{m-1}|$.

Which is of course true, since

$|w_{m+1}-w_{m}|=\left|S_{m+1}/S_m-S_m/S_{m-1}\right| = \left|\frac{S_{m+1}S_{m-1}-S_m^2}{S_mS_{m-1}}\right|=\frac{1}{S_mS_{m-1}}$

So $\frac{|w_{m+1}-w_{m}|}{|w_{m}-w_{m-1}|}=\frac{S_{m-2}}{S_m}\le(2/3)^2$ for $m\ge4$.

$S_{m+1}S_{m-1}-S_m^2=(-1)^{m+1}$, because

$\begin{array}{rcl}S_{m+1}S_{m-1}-S_m^2&=&(S_{m}+S_{m-1})S_{m-1}-S_m^2\\
&=&S_{m-1}^2+S_mS_{m-1}-S_m^2\\
&=&(-1)\left(S_mS_{m-2}-S_{m-1}^2\right)\end{array}$